# Considerations about move semantic for a type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am implementing a type `T`. Although this is not a requirement, users of this type may benefit from move semantic, that is `T(T&&)` and `T& operator=(T&&)`.

Since `T` contains `std::function`'s as member data, I cannot implement move semantic with the `noexcept` guarantees, which would make `T` *less* useful for the user.

Also, for the above reason, my implementation cannot be as simple as: `T(&&) noexcept = default` and `T& operator=(T&&) noexcept = default`

The alternative would be to either offer the user the *non-`noexcept`* versions: `T(&&) = default` and `T& operator=(T&&) = default`; or implement my user defined `noexcept` move semantic in terms of `std::function::swap()` (which is guaranteed to be `noexcept`). In the latter case, I would unfortunately have to take care of all the other member data other than `std::function`'s (ugly!).

So, there are three options:

1. disable move semantic at all
2. implement `T(&&) = default` and `T& operator=(T&&) = default`
3. implement my own `T(&&) noexcept {/* lot of code */}` and `T& operator=(T&&) noexcept {/* lot of code */}`

I know the question is rather subjective, but What would you opt for?

Comment: I would like to know why you can't use the default move constructor.
Shouldn't it work with `T(&&) = default` and `T& operator=(T&&) = default` as
_Inheriting constructors and the implicitly-declared default constructors, copy constructors, move constructors, destructors, copy-assignment operators, move-assignment operators are all noexcept(true) by default, unless they are required to call a function that is noexcept(false), in which case these functions are noexcept(false)._
[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec)

Comment: @SimonKraemer - I think OP's problem is that the std::function move ctor is _not_ declared `noexcept`, and hence his default move ctor will not be `noexcept`.  However, a `noexcept` move ctor can be manually implemented using `swap`.

Comment: There is an open issue about the noexceptness of `swap`: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2062 I think the same reasoning applies here: If there's some kind of Small Object Optimization, then the move ctor can throw because it can do more than just move a pointer. Since the default ctor is noexcept, I'd guess that the move ctor should mirror the noexceptness of `swap`.

Comment: @Useless Ah ok. Trank you.

Comment: Is there a REAL reason to close this question? Or is it just another example of the closeflu virus?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you *really* want the `noexcept` move, you can reduce the amount of boilerplate for option #3 by either:

1. grouping the default-noexcept-moveable members into a nested struct member or private base class, and write a move-ctor which simply moves that (one line for all of them), and then swaps the `std::function`s, or
2. writing a SwapMove template wrapper for storing a `function` in. It just needs to implement the move ctor and assignment operator using swap, and default everything else. OK, you'll also need to either expose the `function` member or forward the function call operator.

Comment: seem valid solutions but #1 would require some refactoring in different places, #2 would be ok if I could use anything in boost:: for this purpose

Comment: So you need a solution which avoids writing or changing any code?

Comment: as much as possible... if there's anything already implemented in boost, for example, it would be ok

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to put all your functions in a std::function inside a  std::vector then swap the vector ?

vector has noexcept move constructor.

EDIT:

To fully expand the needed concepts, i cannot reply in comments.

For your situation (different function signatures) you will require type erasure and some dynamic casts.

Here's some code that uses all the stated concepts in a coment (vector and enum and others ).

Now you can keep a vector of your lambdas , regardless of signature.

```
class LambdaContainer
{
public:
struct GenericContainer {
    virtual  ~GenericContainer(){}
};

template <typename T>
struct SpecializedContainer : GenericContainer
{
    SpecializedContainer(const T& t) : lambda(t){}
    virtual ~SpecializedContainer(){}
    T lambda;

};

private:
 std::shared_ptr<GenericContainer> myLambda;



public:
    template <typename T>
    LambdaContainer(const T& aLambda) : myLambda(new SpecializedContainer<T>(aLambda)){}

    std::shared_ptr<GenericContainer> getContainedLambda()
    {
        return myLambda;
    }



};

enum eFunctions
{
    FCT_INT=0,
    FCT_FLOAT=1
};

...
int main()
{
int aa = 10;
float b = 3.0f;
std::function<void(int)> lambda1 = [aa](int arg)
{
    printf("at this time b plus argument is %d\n ",aa+arg);
};
std::function<int (float, float )> lambda2  = [b] (float arg1, float arg2)
{ printf("calling the sum of floats %f , %f\n"); 
return (int)(arg1+arg2+b);};

std::vector<LambdaContainer> lambdaVector;

lambdaVector.push_back(LambdaContainer(lambda1));
lambdaVector.push_back(LambdaContainer(lambda2));

std::shared_ptr<LambdaContainer::GenericContainer> container = lambdaVector[FCT_INT].getContainedLambda();

LambdaContainer::SpecializedContainer<std::function<void(int)> >* ptr =
        dynamic_cast<LambdaContainer::SpecializedContainer<std::function<void(int)> >*> (container.get());

if (ptr!=NULL)
{
    std::function<void(int)> extractedLambda = ptr->lambda;
    extractedLambda(5);
}
std::shared_ptr<LambdaContainer::GenericContainer> container2 = lambdaVector[FCT_FLOAT].getContainedLambda();

LambdaContainer::SpecializedContainer<std::function<int(float,float)> >* ptr2 =
        dynamic_cast<LambdaContainer::SpecializedContainer<std::function<int(float,float)> >*> (container2.get());

if (ptr2!=NULL)
{
    std::function<int(float,float)> extractedLambda = ptr2->lambda;
    printf("the sum is %d\n",extractedLambda(3.0f,2.0f));
}
```

}

Comment: how would you reference those functions then? v[0], v[1]...it's rather ugly

Comment: I would make an enum, then reference them as v[AWESOME_FUNCTION] , v[STRATEGY_PATTERN_FUNCTION] ... That should take care of the readability of the code :) . Now you can have noexcept code and readable code ... or you can select one of the three solutions you proposed - my main question is if you have a technical reason for not using a vector ?

Comment: oh right an enum...I have no problem with using std::vector. I think this solution is not bad after all

Comment: I forgot to say the std::function's are parametrized with different types, so one vector won't work

Comment: try the code after my edit (i deleted some stuff before pasting, so some typos might occur, but you should be able to get through )